# Uncaught TypeError: json.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, foreach, addeventlistener, stringify

```
let myJSON = { "name": "naam", 
    "schools" : [
        "silver stone"  , 
        "woodlands stone"  , 
        "patthar"
    ],
    "class" : 12 }

myJSON = JSON.stringify(myJSON) ; 
let json = JSON.parse(myJSON) ; 

json.forEach(e => {
     console.log(e.schools) ; 
});
```

I want to populate the school names on the page but not sure why I am getting this error:

> "  Uncaught TypeError: json.forEach is not a function "

can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: you likely want to `json.schools.forEach(shoolName => console.log(shoolName))`

Comment: The words to ask google to get unblocked is: "Tutorial javascript object member method foreach" then the demos make followup questions: "How do I know which member methods are available to which datatypes?"  Then finally: "Why doesn't my variable `typeof(x) == string` have a .forEach member method for me to invoke?" wrap all your variables in `typeof(x)` and observe the output and ask which builtin member methods are available.  The error message given is unhelpful but not wrong. Javascript doesn't know how to `forEach` a `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forEach only works on array-type data.

```
let myJSON = {
"name": "naam" , 
"schools" : [
     "silver stone"  , 
     "woodlands stone"  , 
     "patthar"
], 
"class" : 12}

let info = document.getElementById("info"); 
let clickme = document.getElementById("clickme");
 
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myJSON) ;
/* "json" variable has a object type data */
let json = JSON.parse(myJSON) ; 

// For Each function only works on arrays.
//you can't use it to loop directly on an object
json.schools.forEach(e => {
     console.log(e) ; 
});
```

so to loop in the school array which is located at the json.schools you need to run forEach on "json.school" which is an Array, not on "json" variable which has an object data.